# Delete and renaming file having issues

Tags: java

i got 2 functions which i created 1 is to change Password and 1 to delete the file. so my intention is to run the change password feature first followed by doing the delete file. the code runs properly and creates the new password in a new file. but it does not work when trying to delete the file & renaming need some help pls

```
public static void replaceAdminPassword()throws IOException{

    try {

        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Old Password: ");
        String oldPass = read.nextLine();
        String UserPHash = Utility.getHash(oldPass);
        System.out.println("Enter New Password: ");
        String newPass = read.nextLine();
        String UserNHash = Utility.getHash(newPass);


        read = new Scanner(new File("admin.dat"));
        String line;
        String[] details;
        String input = "";


        File fout = new File("out.dat");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        while (read.hasNextLine()){
            line = read.nextLine();
            details = line.split("\\|");

            if(details[0].equalsIgnoreCase(UserPHash)){
                input = UserNHash;
                bw.write(input);
                System.out.println("Password Changed.");
            }


        }
        bw.close();
        replaceAdminFile();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

}

    public static void replaceAdminFile(){
    File oldFile = new File("admin.dat");
    File newFile = new File("out.dat");
    oldFile.delete();
    newFile.renameTo(oldFile);

}
```

Comment: no exception it just creates the out.dat with the new password

Comment: yeah the delete file and rename file does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use new io API instead :

```
Files.delete(Paths.get("admin.dat"));
Files.move(Paths.get("out.dat"), Paths.get("admin.dat"));
```

You might want to check the documentation of [move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) and [delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-).

Don't forget to import `java.nio.file.Files` and `java.nio.file.Paths`.

Comment: sorry i got a error saying : The Method Delete(path) in the type files is not applicable for the arguements(String)

Comment: hmmm, i am not sure why they say this but is it because of my eclipse program? i got a error: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: admin.dat: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @Ken close the scanner before calling the method, add `read.close();`.

Comment: ok, now i got another problem my out.dat suddenly becomes empty

Comment: @Ken do you mean "out.dat"  or "admin.dat" after it was moved ?

Comment: let me go check i think i did a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75041/discussion-between-ken-and-jean-francois-savard).

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Scanner by calling "read.close()" otherwise the file is still open and you can't rename or delete it.